# How to use ASP.net code in .HTML page?

Tags: html, asp.net, dynamic

I have a static website made on .HTML page by using bootstrap framework. I have a large amount is text (Paragraph) i want to insert it in the database by using text datatype with the help of ASP.net. How i can use ASP.net code in html page???

Comment: You need to use any scripting language jquey, javascript etc to call server side methods.

Answer (score 1):

Use a form post at HTML side and send data to server side methods and do Database manipulation there only.

Or if you do not want to reload page on post use Ajax to post data and do the manipulation. That will be good I guess.

Comment: thanks for your efficient reply. Its requirement of our college project that we have to use ASP.net. If u have any useful link or site in that regard plz share with me.Cos till now i am unable to find any help in that regard.??

Comment: There are plethora of sites where you can learn basics of .net and apply that in your project. As you did not mention what exactly you want to learn I am writing some reference site over here please go through that http://www.dotnetcurry.com/, https://www.tutorialspoint.com/, https://www.codeproject.com/. You can find some already built project on codeproject which you can use to learn from.

Comment: I have done with a website made on .HTML pages by using bootstrap framework(by using visual studio as IDE). I have  large amount of text (Paragraphs) i want to insert it in the database with the help of ASP.net. How i can use ASP.net code in .html page???

It would work If i manually replace .html extension with .aspx extension.. But in that way how i would get .aspx.cs file(for initialization and event handling, etc).